# Cross origin iframe overwrites sessionid

Tags: java, spring, angular, spring-boot, iframe

I have a Springboot/angular component (this is an angular component that is authenticated by Spring security and loads its data from a Spring REST API) . This springboot/angular component is being loaded within an iframe of a JAVA EE application.

They are also loaded on separate contexts, localhost:8080 and localhost:7001 respectively.

Problem is, whenever the springboot/angular component is loaded and authenticated in the iframe, it overwrites the Jsessionid, such that the next HTTP request I make on the JAVA EE application, is no longer the original Jsessionid and hence results in an error.

How can I avoid the Jsessionid from being overwritten in this manner while using a cross-origin iframe?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Code in localhost:7001 (JAVA EE application) containing the iframe:
basically, what happens is I call a custom post request to my spring processLogin controller in order to authenticate the spring/angular component, and have the request display in the iframe.

```
<body>
<script>


    function sendForm(){

    var username = document.getElementById("sessionUser").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("sessionPw").value;

    var param = {};
    param['username'] = username;
    param['password'] = password;


    post('http://localhost:8080/processLogin', param );
    }
    </script>


         <iframe   id=menuFrame frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;" src=""></iframe>


</body>
```

Comment: **Moderator Note**: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you post a question, they belong to the site and its users. Even if it is no longer useful to you, it might be helpful to someone in the future. The answerers would have also put an effort in writing their answer, which would no longer be useful if you have removed the content from the post. Also, note that by posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact you are in two separated contexts, so you have two different sessionId. In order to share your sessionId you should implement load balancing or another mechanisms that allow to share sessions at server level.